# Laravel stylesheet works on localhost, but on the server some pages have the style and some don't

Tags: laravel

I made an application based on a Udemy course when I made the project on the localhost the stylesheet worked perfect but when I decided to uploaded to the internet it works only in some pages not to all of them so if you go to.

http://mhdevelopment.gr/cmanager/public/ and make an acccount login and after manage your contacts when you go to edit section, and in the create section it doesn't work.

Comment: People generally won't make an account in order to help you. Please make things easier for your readership by showing all of the CSS in the question itself. Also, make sure all of your CSS assets are loading, by examining your network tab.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply .
im new here and my english is not so good thats why im sorry.
So i saw in the network tab but the css is not loading

Comment: No worries, we are happy to help people whose English is not so good. However, we do ask that questions contain everything that a reader needs to help you; have a read of [the help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help) when you get a moment.

Comment: If you can see problems in the network tab, please add the details of those problems into your question. Do you get 404 on some CSS assets?

Comment: Re-check, working fine!

Comment: yes i fixed i add the full path of the css files